# Is there any way to listen device location on or off?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `Geolocator` plugin. It's working. but not display a message immediately. the message is displayed like after 2,3 minutes. It does not display real-time.
`Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled()` is future, can't listen right?

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
                  future: Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled(),
                    builder: (context,snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasData){
                      if(!snapshot.data)
                      return CustomText(
                              text: 'GPS Interrupted',
                          );
                      else
                        return Container();
                    } else{
                      return Container();
                    }
                    }
                )
```

I used this widget like this,

```
 bottom: PreferredSize(child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way, It's working.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    const Duration checkingTime = Duration(seconds:5);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(checkingTime, (Timer t) => checkLocation());//Using GeoLocator
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
   if( _timer != null) _timer.cancel();
  }


  void checkLocation(){
    Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled().then(locationService);
  }

  void locationService(bool result){
    if(!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      if(result)
        isLocationEnable = true;
      else
        isLocationEnable = false;
    });
  }
```